# no puedo acceder a mi sitio con www montado en ubuntu 16.04 con virtualhost

Tags: ubuntu, php7, apache2, virtualhost

por ejemplo si pongo ejemplo.dominio.com si logra cargar el sitio, pero si pongo www.ejemplo.dominio.com me da el siguiente error

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

En el archivo virtual host tengo lo siguiente:

El servidor esta montado en ubuntu 16.04

```
ServerAdmin contacto.admin@gmail.com
ServerName  ejemplo.dominio.com
ServerAlias www.ejemplo.dominio.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/ejemplo.dominio.com/public_html/

<Directory /var/www/ejemplo.dominio.com/public_html/>
        Require all granted
         AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Comment: ya reviste que los permisos de la carpeta estén bien

Comment: alguna pista en `/var/log/apache/error.log` ?